# Trouble iterating through Array and sorting into conditional to check for each Array item

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to iterate through each of the declared arrays `all_sprites_x_coordinates[], all_sprites_width[], all_sprites_height[]` and substitute them into the if statement accordingly (i've shown you as an example below). Basically this function is to make sure the player in my game safely spawns, so it must check if there are no sprites within a 6 pixel distance to the left and right of the car. Each sprite within the Arrays are other sprites that exist in the game. I'm having trouble with syntax and problem solving in general, as I am VERY new to C so succinct explanations would really help me understand. I also think that the if statement should be in the for loop.

```
    bool determineSafeSpawn(sprite_id sprite1, sprite_id sprite2){
      int car_x = sprite_x(player_car);
      int all_sprites_x_coordinates[] = { sprite_x(rock), sprite_x(zombie), sprite_x(bat), sprite_x(tree), sprite_x(hill), sprite_x(bush), sprite_x(house_one), sprite_x(fuel_station)};
      int all_sprites_width[] = { ROCK_WIDTH, ZOMBIE_WIDTH, BAT_WIDTH, TREE_WIDTH, HILL_WIDTH, BUSH_WIDTH, HOUSE_ONE_WIDTH, FUEL_STATION_WIDTH};
      int all_sprites_height[] = { ROCK_HEIGHT, ZOMBIE_HEIGHT, BAT_HEIGHT, TREE_HEIGHT, HILL_HEIGHT, BUSH_HEIGHT, HOUSE_ONE_HEIGHT, FUEL_STATION_HEIGHT};

      bool flag = false;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(all_sprites) / sizeof(sprite) && !flag; ++i) {
      //flag &&= overlaps(all_sprites[i], your_target_sprite);
        // check if any sprite within array is within 6 pixels of car
        if ((((car_x < all_sprites_x_coordinates[] + all_sprites_width[] + 6) && (car_x > all_sprites_x_coordinates[] + all_sprites_width[])) || ((car_x + CAR_WIDTH > all_sprites_x_coordinates[] - 6) && (car_x + CAR_WIDTH < all_sprites_x_coordinates[])) && speed == 0)) {
        // move left or right and search again
        } else {
          // it is safe to spawn
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble with syntax* we are not human compilers, with all those long lines, it's difficult to see if there is syntax problem. So if the compiler complains, then please post the output of the compiler. And it would be best to post a [mcve], like I said, we are not human compilers.

Comment: What exactly is this `all_sprites_x_coordinates[] + all_sprites_width[] + 6` supposed to mean? Did you mean `all_sprites_x_coordinates[i] + all_sprites_width[i]  + 6`?

Comment: It means: the X coordinate of a sprite + the width of the same sprite + 6 pixels. Like I said, I was unsure what went inside these brackets. i does make sense though. As you can see what is inside both of the `sizeof()` parameters, they need to be replaced as `all_sprites` and `sprite` do not exist. What would I put inside these brackets? Or am I not understanding the for loop properly?